# Run function in same module and file in different process

Tags: multiprocessing, julia

If I have the following Julia code snippet, is there any way I can run the `for` loop with multiple processes without putting `complicated` into an extra file and doing something like `@everywhere include("complicated.jl")`?

Otherwise, the processes don't seem to be able to find the function.

```
function complicated(x)
    # long and complicated computation
    x^2
end

function run()
    results = []
    for i in 1:4
        push!(results, @spawn complicated(3))
    end
    return mean(results)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just annotate the expression you want to define in all processors with `@everywhere` macro (in Julia everything is an expression):

```rb
julia> addprocs(Sys.CPU_CORES)
12-element Array{Int64,1}:
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
 11
 12
 13

julia> @everywhere function complicated(x)
           # long and complicated computation
           x^2
       end

julia> function main()
           @sync results = @parallel vcat for i in 1:4
               complicated(3)
           end
           return mean(results)
       end
main (generic function with 1 method)

julia> main()
9.0
```

**Note**: `run` is an already existing function in `Base`.